# FactoryGirl.create doesn't save Mongoid relations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, factory-bot

I have two classes:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_one :preference
  attr_accessible :name
  field :name, type: String
end

class Preference
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :somepref
  field :somepref, type: Boolean
end
```

And I have two factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    preference
    name 'John'
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :preference do
    somepref true
  end
end
```

After I create a `User` both documents are saved in the DB, but `Preference` document is missing `user_id` field and so has_one relation doesn't work when I read `User` from the DB.

I've currently fixed it by adding this piece of code in `User` factory:

```
after(:create) do |user|
  #user.preference.save! #without this user_id field doesn't get saved
end
```

Can anyone explain to me why is this happening and is there a better fix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongoid block until created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263565/mongoid-block-until-created)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoid seems to be lacking support here.

When FactoryGirl creates a user, it first has to create the preference for that new user. As the new user does not have an id yet, the preference can't store it either.

In general, when you try create parent & child models in one operation, you need two steps:

1. create the parent, persist to database so it get's an id.
2. create the child for the parent and persist it.

Step two would end up in an after(:create) block. Like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'John'

    after(:create) do |user|
       preference { create(:preference, user: user) }
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code didn't work at first, but I've rewritten the line inside the block like this:
user.preference = create(:preference, user: user)
and it works.

Comment: Any idea what to do if I have validates_presence_of :preference in User class? Validation fails before after(:create) callback is executed.

Comment: Oops, yeah, I forgot the user. As to validations: you might need to use build instead of create.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22280081/1120015):

> To ensure that you can always immediately read back the data you just
>   wrote using `Mongoid`, you need to set the database session options
>
> ```
> consistency: :strong, safe: true
> ```
>
> neither of which are the default.